# Fail Safe Iterators: Memory Penalties?

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, hashmap

So was just going through ConcurrentHashMap and it seems to be a threadsafe implementation with a fail-safe iterator.

The implementation of fail-safe iterators are created using copy of the data structures and hence this prevents the problem of Concurrent Modification would have introduced. But it adds a penalty of the added memory usage.

How high is this penalty? Is this always going to be equal to the size of the data structure?

Considering my plan to hold a lot of context in ConcurrentHashMap, it would really be detrimental for my application memory footprint to double suddenly if I iterate.

Also if there are 'n' threads iterating the data structure at the same time, is the memory penalty 'n' times the size of the data structure?

This seems to be a costly penalty to pay for Fail Safe iterators. If the penalty is off this order, can I prevent using the fail-safe iterators by combining fail-fast iterators with mutexes?

Comment: It seems to me that if you ever feel the need to iterate on a hash map your data structure design has failed fundamentally.

Comment: @ZanLynx, why?  It's perfectly reasonable to want associations and to want to be able to iterate over the associations, and iterating over `HashMap`s isn't really that expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `ConcurrentHashMap`'s iterators don't make any copies like this.  The worst-case scenario is that it retains a reference to a segment of the hash table longer than the map itself, but that reference will get GC'd as soon as the iterator is discarded or iterates past that segment of the map.  The iterator itself takes O(1) memory, and O(1) time to create.

The iterator is *weakly consistent*, which means it is allowed but not obligated to reflect changes in the map since the iterator was created.

Comment: Excellent, that had me worrying for a minute. Any documentation that will give me idea about what exactly weakly consistent iterators entail and what it doesn't guarantee?

Comment: This one?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#entrySet()  "The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction."

Comment: Thanks this has been a great help :)

Comment: how does a weakly consistent iterator work without a copy of the data structure?

Comment: Wouldn't deletion/addition just corrupt the iterator?  Or if it always points to the data structure in a thread safe manner, why would it be "weakly" consistent

Comment: It's weakly consistent because deletion and addition might change the iterator in front of it, but it never corrupts the iterator; the linked list buckets can be traversed in a thread-safe manner.  If the hash table gets expanded, however, the iterator will continue to refer to the old table and not reflect further updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71739/discussion-between-desert-ice-and-louis-wasserman).